# Average distance from point to spherical square?

Tags: spherical-geometry

I need to calculate the average distance from a point to a $4$ sided spherical polygon. Can someone point me to the right direction?
I guess either the average point of a spherical square or centroid might also work for my purposes.

Comment: What are the "average point" and "centroid" of a region on the sphere?